# Loading and transposing eight 8-element float vectors

Tags: optimization, intel, intrinsics, avx, avx2

In one of a tight loop running a DSP algorithm I need to load eight 8-element float vectors given a base data pointer and offsets in AVX2 integer register. My current fastest code looks like this:

```
void LoadTransposed(
    const float* data, __m256i offsets,
    __m256& v0, __m256& v1, __m256& v2, __m256& v3, __m256& v4, __m256& v5, __m256& v6, __m256& v7)
{
    const __m128i offsetsLo = _mm256_castsi256_si128(offsets);
    const __m128i offsetsHi = _mm256_extracti128_si256(offsets, 1);
    __m256 a0 = _mm256_loadu_ps(data + (uint32)_mm_cvtsi128_si32(offsetsLo   ));
    __m256 a1 = _mm256_loadu_ps(data + (uint32)_mm_extract_epi32(offsetsLo, 1));
    __m256 a2 = _mm256_loadu_ps(data + (uint32)_mm_extract_epi32(offsetsLo, 2));
    __m256 a3 = _mm256_loadu_ps(data + (uint32)_mm_extract_epi32(offsetsLo, 3));
    __m256 a4 = _mm256_loadu_ps(data + (uint32)_mm_cvtsi128_si32(offsetsHi   ));
    __m256 a5 = _mm256_loadu_ps(data + (uint32)_mm_extract_epi32(offsetsHi, 1));
    __m256 a6 = _mm256_loadu_ps(data + (uint32)_mm_extract_epi32(offsetsHi, 2));
    __m256 a7 = _mm256_loadu_ps(data + (uint32)_mm_extract_epi32(offsetsHi, 3));

    // transpose
    const __m256 t0 = _mm256_unpacklo_ps(a0, a1);
    const __m256 t1 = _mm256_unpackhi_ps(a0, a1);
    const __m256 t2 = _mm256_unpacklo_ps(a2, a3);
    const __m256 t3 = _mm256_unpackhi_ps(a2, a3);
    const __m256 t4 = _mm256_unpacklo_ps(a4, a5);
    const __m256 t5 = _mm256_unpackhi_ps(a4, a5);
    const __m256 t6 = _mm256_unpacklo_ps(a6, a7);
    const __m256 t7 = _mm256_unpackhi_ps(a6, a7);
    __m256 v = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t0, t2, 0x4E);
    const __m256 tt0 = _mm256_blend_ps(t0, v, 0xCC);
    const __m256 tt1 = _mm256_blend_ps(t2, v, 0x33);
    v = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t1, t3, 0x4E);
    const __m256 tt2 = _mm256_blend_ps(t1, v, 0xCC);
    const __m256 tt3 = _mm256_blend_ps(t3, v, 0x33);
    v = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t4, t6, 0x4E);
    const __m256 tt4 = _mm256_blend_ps(t4, v, 0xCC);
    const __m256 tt5 = _mm256_blend_ps(t6, v, 0x33);
    v = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t5, t7, 0x4E);
    const __m256 tt6 = _mm256_blend_ps(t5, v, 0xCC);
    const __m256 tt7 = _mm256_blend_ps(t7, v, 0x33);
    v0 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(tt0, tt4, 0x20);
    v1 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(tt1, tt5, 0x20);
    v2 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(tt2, tt6, 0x20);
    v3 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(tt3, tt7, 0x20);
    v4 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(tt0, tt4, 0x31);
    v5 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(tt1, tt5, 0x31);
    v6 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(tt2, tt6, 0x31);
    v7 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(tt3, tt7, 0x31);
}
```

As you can see, I'm already using blends instead of shuffles to reduce port 5 pressure. I also opted for `_mm_cvtsi128_si32` when loading extracting 1st vector element, which is only 1uop, instead of 2uops in case of inconspicuous `_mm_extract_epi32`. Also, extracting the lower and higher lanes manually seems to help the compiler a bit and removes redundant `vextracti128` instructions.

I've tried equivalent code using gather instructions, which as predicted turned out to be 2x slower, as it's doing effectively 64 loads under the hood:

```
void LoadTransposed_Gather(
    const float* data, __m256i offsets,
    __m256& v0, __m256& v1, __m256& v2, __m256& v3, __m256& v4, __m256& v5, __m256& v6, __m256& v7)
{
    v0 = _mm256_i32gather_ps(data + 0, offsets, 4);
    v1 = _mm256_i32gather_ps(data + 1, offsets, 4);
    v2 = _mm256_i32gather_ps(data + 2, offsets, 4);
    v3 = _mm256_i32gather_ps(data + 3, offsets, 4);
    v4 = _mm256_i32gather_ps(data + 4, offsets, 4);
    v5 = _mm256_i32gather_ps(data + 5, offsets, 4);
    v6 = _mm256_i32gather_ps(data + 6, offsets, 4);
    v7 = _mm256_i32gather_ps(data + 7, offsets, 4);
}
```

Is there any way to speed this (the former snippet) up even further? According to VTune and IACA, the biggest offender is high port 0 and 5 pressure (probably due to `vpextrd` used during offset extraction from __m128i registers  and all the `vunpckhps`, `vunpcklps` and `vshufps` used during transpose).

Comment: Compilers normally optimize `_mm_extract_epi32(v, 0)` into the same asm as `_mm_cvtsi128_si32` (e.g. `vmovd eax, xmm0`), but yeah it's not a bad thing to do it explicitly.  And yes, good plan to unpack to `__m128i` first; there is no `vpextrd r32, ymm, i` only an XMM source, and I'm not surprised that some compilers aren't good at CSEing the shuffles from the `__m256i` extract intrinsic if you use it multiple times.  (A really smart compiler would probably store/reload for at least the last 6 elements.)

Comment: Some further ideas to reduce port5 pressure: You could extract 64 bits, and shift/and each 32bit half from it. And each pair of 128bit shuffles could also be replaced by one shuffle and two blends (not sure if it is worth it), or actually, you could load the high and low half of each `aX` separately (`VINSERTF128 (YMM, YMM, M128, I8)` takes `1*p015+1*p23` on Haswell or later according to [uops.info](https://uops.info/html-instr/VINSERTF128_YMM_YMM_M128_I8.html))

Comment: @chtz Both suggestions worked prtty nice! That is, extracting 64bits and shifting to reduce number of `vpextrd` and using `VINSERTF128` instead of `VPEM2F`128`. The overall gain is tiny (around 8%), but still something.

Answer (score 2):

Do your offsets have a pattern, like a fixed stride that you could just scale?

If not, perhaps pass them around as a struct instead of an `__m256i` if you're just going to need to extract them anyway?

Or if you're using SIMD to calculate the offsets (so they're naturally in a `__m256i` in the first place): **store/reload to a local array When you need all 8 elements would save shuffle port bandwidth**.  Maybe `_mm_cvtsi128_si32` / `_mm_extract_epi32(offsetsLo, 1))` to get the first 1 or 2 offsets via ALU operations, with a couple cycles lower latency than store -> reload store forwarding.

e.g. `alignas(32) uint32_t offsets[8];` and `_mm256_store_si256` into it.  (With some compilers, you may need to stop it from "optimizing" that into ALU extracts.  You can use `volatile` on the array as a nasty hack to work around that.  (But be careful not to defeat optimization more than necessary, e.g. load into tmp vars instead of accessing the volatile array multiple times, if you do want each element more than once.  This will always defeat constant-propagation, for FP will defeat stuff like using the low element of a vector *as* a scalar with no shuffle necessary.)

---

2/clock load throughput, and efficient store forwarding from a vector store to scalar reloads of 32-bit elements makes this good (maybe 7 cycle latency IIRC, for a 256-bit store).

Especially if you're doing this transpose in a loop with other ALU work on the transpose result, so the loop mostly bottlenecks on port 5 in the back-end.  The extra load uops shouldn't bottleneck on load ports, especially if there are any L1d cache misses.  (In which case replays cost extra cycles on ports for instructions that *consume* the load results, not of load uops themselves).

Also fewer front-end uops:

- 1 store (p237+p4 micro-fused) + 1 vmovd (p0) + 7 loads (p23) is only 9 total front-end (fused-domain) uops
- vs. vextracti128 + 2x vmovd + 6x vpextrd = 15 ALU uops for port 0 and port 5

Store/reload is fine on Zen/Zen2 as well.

IceLake has more ALU shuffle throughput (some vector shuffles can run on another port as well as p5) but store/reload is still a good strategy when you need all the elements and there are 8 of them.  Especially for throughput at a small cost in latency.

---

---

@Witek902 reports (in comments) that [@chtz's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60157799/loading-and-transposing-eight-8-element-float-vectors/60161515#comment106424002_60157799) of **building the transpose out of `vmovups xmm` + `vinsertf128` reduces the port 5 shuffle throughput bottleneck on HSW / SKL and gives a speedup in practice**.  `vinsertf128 y,y,mem,i` is 2 uops (can't micro-fuse) for p015 + p23 on Intel.  So it's more like a blend, not needing the shuffle port. (It's also going to be excellent on Bulldozer-family / Zen1 which handle YMM regs as two 128-bit halves.)

Doing only 128-bit loads is also nice for Sandybridge / IvyBridge, where misaligned 256-bit loads are extra expensive.

And on any CPU; if an offset happens to be an odd multiple of 16-byte alignment, neither 128-bit load will cross a cache-line boundary.  So no uop replays of dependent ALU uops creating extra back-end port pressure.

Comment: Store+reload looked promising, but the problem is that the compiler converts it back to vextracti128 + vpextrd. Happens both with MSVC and clang.

Comment: @Witek902 Oh, well that sounds like a "missed optimization" compiler bug.  (That general category includes attempts at optimization that actually pessimize what your wrote in the source.)  IDK if there's already a clang bug open for this.  You could force the issue with `volatile`, but that would defeat the possibility of constant propagation, and forcing the compiler to read the array exactly once for each time the source does could maybe hurt code-gen.

Comment: I've workaround the compiler by using `volatile` and it turned out that trick with store forwarding really works. The overall gain is around 6%. The strange thing though is that it even better combines with transpose based on 8 `VINSERTF128`s (at the cost of doubled loads). So the whole algoritm that does 24 loads in total is faster than the one that does only 8.

Comment: @Witek902: Good idea.  If your 256-bit loads were ever *evenly* split across a cache-line boundary, 2x 128-bit loads would avoid the cache line split cost.  That cost include replays of dependent ALU uops, which in this case includes shuffles.  See [Are load ops deallocated from the RS when they dispatch, complete or some other time?](//stackoverflow.com/q/59905395) (especially discussion in comments/chat).  I still need to update [How can I accurately benchmark unaligned access speed on x86\_64](//stackoverflow.com/a/45129784) based on that new understanding.

Comment: @Witek902: oh, but of course the main benefit is that the insert ALU uop can run on any port, as chtz pointed out.

Comment: Yeah, the loads are 16-byte aligned, but not necessarily 32-byte aligned in my case. Using 128-loads eliminated cache line split completely. That could be the main reason for improved performance.

Comment: @Witek902: Probably a combination of factors, especially since you have port 5 ALU uops dependent on loads: the problems can possibly *compound* each other via uop replays. If you weren't quite bottlenecked on port 5 throughput then replays could make that the case. (Normally uops are scheduled oldest-ready first, so I think the worst case effect should be limited. If p5 falls behind loads, port 5 uops won't be dispatching just-in-time / optimistically to bypass forward from a load.  Instead it will be working on even older shuffles that are still waiting.  But old cache misses could hurt...)

Comment: At least that's the current state of my understanding of how uop scheduling and replays might interact in this case.  Either way, eliminating cache-line splits is rarely a bad thing, and even without replays `vinsertf128` reduces the p5 bottleneck.